# How do I restore newer messages to old phone?

Tags: android-11

I purchased a new phone that I don't like so I am returning it. I'll temporarily have to use my old phone. How do I restore just the new messages on the new phone too the old phone?

Edit for more detail:
I only want the most recent messages because the phone already has most messages so those messages would be duplicated.

Comment: Welcome to Android Enthusiasts Stack Exchange. By "messages", did you mean SMS or other social messaging apps? Also, could you mention both device models?

Comment: One option would be to wipe your old phone, then set it up as if it were new and be sure to use the option to bring over all the messages from your previously new phone.